# Ошибка с типом возвращаемых данных TS2322

Tags: typescript, angular, типы-данных, promise, typescript-типы

Использую canActivate в сервисе AuthGuard , где я в методе canActivate обращаюсь `this.authService.isAuthenticated()` что возвращает мне `Promise`. Потом использую метод .then где и выделяется у меня все ошибкой:

> Error: src/app/auth.guard.ts:27:9 error TS2322: Type 'Promise<boolean | Observable |
> undefined>' is not assignable to type 'boolean | Observable |
> Promise'

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, CanActivate, Router, RouterStateSnapshot } from "@angular/router";
import { of,Observable } from "rxjs";
import { AuthService } from "./auth.service";

@Injectable({ 
    providedIn: 'root' 
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

    constructor(public authService: AuthService, public router: Router) { }

    canActivate(
        route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
        state: RouterStateSnapshot
      ): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
        return this.authService.isAuthenticated().then(isAuth => {
          if (isAuth) {
            return true
          } else {
            this.router.navigate(['/'], {
              queryParams: {
                auth: false
              }
            })
          }
        })
      }
}
```

код Authservice.isAuthenticated()

```
 isAuthenticated(): Promise<boolean> {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                resolve(this.isAuth)
                    , 1000
            })
        })
    }
```

скрин
[image: оишбка]

Answer (score 0):

Проблема, естественно, здесь:

```
this.authService.isAuthenticated().then(isAuth => {
  if (isAuth) {
    return true
  } else {
    this.router.navigate(['/'], {
      queryParams: {
        auth: false
      }
    })
  }
})
```

Ошибка так и сообщает, что возвращаемый тип не соответствует объявленному, то есть:

Тип, который вы возвращаете (тут идет перечисление их возможных значений) `'Promise<boolean | Observable<boolean> | undefined>'` не соответствует объявленному (тоже перечисление) `'boolean | Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean>'`.

В частности `undefined` нет среди объявленных возвращаемых типов данных (а вы его возвращаете неявно), поэтому надо что-то вернуть в конце среди перечисленного. Думаю, что вот это

```
return this.router.navigate(['/'], {
  queryParams: {
    auth: false
  }
})
```

Тогда метод можно переписать так:

```
this.authService.isAuthenticated().then(isAuth => {
  if (isAuth) {
    return true;
  }

  return this.router.navigate(['/'], {
    queryParams: {
      auth: false
    }
  });
});
```